# Detect keyboard on windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, keyboard, detection

I have been looking for a way to either detect a touchscreen device (when it uses the pointer device driver instead of a touchscreen display driver) or to detect when a keyboard is present from within C# & WPF.

Please note that this is under Windows 7 embedded, not windows 8.

I have seen some references to system.management et al. but am unsure how to go about using these in this way.

Essentially this is for a WPF keyboard to appear if no keyboard is attached and the user enters a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found this solution a few days ago and it seems like it should work well as it will also not display the onscreen keyboard if a keyboard is attached to a touchscreen device (at least it shouldn't unless the OS overrides it, I have yet to test this properly)

In this method I go through the usb HID list using a Nuget library called HIDSHARP to see if a keyboard is attached by looking for the word keyboard in the description.

Then I go through the Management objects to find a ps/2 keyboard if a USB is not found.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// TEST AND SET GLOBAL KEYBOARD ATTACHED BOOL keyB
    /// </summary>
    internal static void TestKeyboard()
    {
        keyB = false;

        //FIND WHETHER A USB KEYBOARD IS PLUGGED IN
        HidSharp.HidDeviceLoader hd = new HidSharp.HidDeviceLoader();

        foreach (HidSharp.HidDevice item in hd.GetDevices())
        {
            if (item.ProductName.Contains("Keyboard"))
            {
                keyB = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        //FIND WHETHER A PS/2 KEYBOARD IS PLUGGED IN.
        string query = "select * from Win32_Keyboard";
        System.Management.ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery(query);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oQuery);
        ManagementObjectCollection recordSet = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject record in recordSet)
        {
            if (record.Properties["Description"].Value.ToString().Contains("Keyboard"))
            {
                keyB = true;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the textbox was selected via Touch you should get the [`GotTouchCapture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gottouchcapture(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`TouchDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.touchdown(v=vs.110).aspx) event. You could register to one of those and show the keyboard if it is fired...

Comment: Ah wow, trying to do this programmatically and checking the event type but first touchdown would fire then mousedown was overriding it. Changed to using a specific function for the touchdownpreview event and boom, it worked. Thanks man I really appreciate it.

p.s. now how to I go about telling SO that you answered my question?

Comment: @Slipoch you mark his answer as correct there should be an option for you where the arrows and the zero are.

Comment: Ah bugger, nope the touchdown event did not work (I thought it was but it is treating the touchscreen as a mouse) Does not even seem to fire the touchdown event, sorry stuffed myself up with my test code.

Comment: @Slipoch: Are you sure you have a "real touchscreen" and not one simulating a mouse?

Comment: That's what I meant by _(when it uses the pointer device driver instead of a touchscreen display driver)_ Hence why I wanted to try to detect a keyboard prescence rather than try to detect touches

Comment: @Slipoch: Ah, sorry - did not see that. In that case there is no reliable way to detect that, as from the point of view of the PC there is no touchscreen...

Comment: @ChrFin I have found a method of detecting it through usb connections, do you know of any way to detect prescence of PS/2 connections?

Comment: @Slipoch: I could only imagine through WMI an searching for such a device, but that wouldnt  be very reliable IMO...